# Why does Flask's app.config.from_object() behave differently with gunicorn?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm using Flask with virtualenv, and my demo Flask app is structured as follows:

```
app/
    hello.py
config/
    settings.py
venv/
    virtualenv files
```

Contents of `hello.py`

```
from flask import Flask


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object("config.settings")

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return app.config["HELLO"]

    return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
```

`settings.py` contains just 2 values

```
DEBUG = True
HELLO = "Hello there from /config !"
```

I can run this successfully with gunicorn using `gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:9000 --access-logfile - "app.hello:create_app()"`, it works without any errors.

However, running `python app/hello.py` from root results in the error `ImportError: No module named 'config'`. It seems that flask is unable to find the config directory when executed in this manner.

I could move the `config` directory inside `app`, but doing so would cause errors with gunicorn instead. Is it not possible to have both ways "just work" ? More importantly, why and what is happening ?

Comment: Does adding a `__init__.py` file into config ,so that it is a package, help?

Comment: I tried adding an empty `__init__.py` into `config/` earlier, but it didn't help. The same error occurs.

Comment: You can try to import config.settings manually and then using from_object(config.settings). Maybe gunicorn does manipulate PYTHONPATH somehow. You could try to add your folder to pythonpath so that config.settings can be imported. (the manully importing shouldn't change anything but you will probaly see that you can't import the settings module.)

Comment: Hmm you're right. After a `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:.`, `python app/hello.py` works.

Comment: I think removing `instance_relative_config=True` part will do the trick ...

Comment: @Shankar `instance_relative_config=True` is used to set the `instance` folder location to be relative. I'm not using that yet ...

Comment: @peonicles I am unable to reproduce the error after adding `__init__.py` to the config folder as syntonym suggested

Answer (score 3):

Not the most elegant yet still perfectly working solution:

```
from os.path import abspath, join
from flask import Flask


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    config_file_path = abspath(
        join(app.instance_path, '../config/settings.py')
    )
    app.config.from_pyfile(config_file_path)

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return app.config["HELLO"]

    return app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
```

Addition after considering the comment. In order for Flask to properly import `config.settings`, the path to app root has to be inside `sys.path`. It can easily be achieved by adding a single line in the original script:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
```

So the final `hello.py` looks like:

```
import os
import sys
from flask import Flask


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
    app.config.from_object("config.settings")

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return app.config["HELLO"]

    return app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
```

Even more bullet-proof solution would be

```
app_root_path = os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(app.instance_path, '..')
)
sys.path.insert(0, app_root_path)
```

This way we do not depend on what `os.getcwd()` returns: it does not always have to return the app root path.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you did there. It's curious that `os.getcwd()` actually returns the app root directory, but somehow `app.config.from_object("config.settings")` doesn't work though.

Comment: @peonicles Your comment made me understand that `os.getcwd()` has to be in `sys.path` in order for our import to work. I've edited my answer to reflect this idea.

Comment: To be more precise, the app's root path has to be in `sys.path` in order for import to work.

Comment: @arrakis_sun there is an `Flask.root_path`

Comment: @Shankar in this case `app.root_path` and `app.instance_path` return the same thing